# Import "own" Font in Monodevelop

Tags: c#, fonts, monodevelop

Is it possible to import fonts into Monodevelop (editor) ? 
I have found this fond: http://input.fontbureau.com/info/ 
and it looks pretty cool and crisp and I would love to use it in Monodevelop. Im working on macOS high Sierra. 
Greetings

Comment: Do you mean into Unity (thus the tag)? Or do you mean the monodevelop editor?

Comment: I mean in monodevlop editor. The place where I write the code for my scripts :)

Comment: what do you mean with "import". As an asset to use in your project, or as a replacement for the Monodevelop UI's own font? Because as an asset, this font is not free, so at the very least you need to pay Font Bureau for the rights to use it, but as a font replacement for the UI, that sounds like something you should first be checking the Monodevelop docs and github issue tracker for.

Comment: I mean I just want another font when editing scripts... not as an asset. Just an font for the text editor mono develop